# How to assign a value created dynamicly

Tags: jquery

I am trying to assing a value from a input that is created dynamicly from ajax also the input recieves the id value with a variable here is my input:

```
html += '<input type="text" class="form-control hidden-print" id="' + picFile.name + '"/>';
```

And this is what I want to do:

```
var value = $('#' + picFile.name);
```

Then I show this

```
html+= '<label>' + value + '</label>';
```

But Im only get this: [Object][Object]

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/qmpy0819/)

Comment: what is `val`? It looks like it's an array. You should inspect `val`, figure out what you want from it, and add *that* to the label (eg `val[0].value` or something)

Comment: `var val = $('#' + picFile.name).val();`

Comment: @iownthegame I try with your code but know I get undefinied on my label.

Comment: have you check if the  `$('#' + picFile.name)` exists or not? since you need to have the <input> element rendered before you select it.

Comment: The input its created with ajax, im trying to upload a sample code to jsfiddle.

Comment: Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/qmpy0819/

Comment: `picFile` does not contain the property name

Comment: Does this do what you want `var val = $('#files').val().split('\\')[2];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely you are not "creating" your string into real elements and therefor you can't access it's `value`. If that is the case, you could try creating the `html` string into an element first like this:

Assuming `html` in your ajax variable:

`// I don't know where you are getting picFile.name so make sure that object exists
var val = $(html).find('#' + picFile.name).val();`

Also, are you trying to append your label to the same `html` string and create both an `input` and a `label` element?

if so then:

`html+= '<label>' + val + '</label>';`

If not:

`html = '<label>' + val + '</label>';`

Comment: What I wanna do its a little weird , but I decided create the input hidden and then with the ajax I'm going to remove the hidden property. But here are your points.